# How to create condition for a field in SQL

Tags: sql, date, criteria, conditional-statements, restriction

How can i restrict the value entered for a field in SQL

```
Appointment ( Appointment_ID, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Time )
```

I have to restrict the value entering should be

```
Appointment_Date (Monday – Friday) 
Appointment_Time (08:00- 17:00)
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx ?

Comment: SQL doesn't seem like the right place to validate this

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Sql Server?

Comment: Thanks @Marc B that was really help full

Answer (score 0):

You can use check constraint for that.
Extract the day from the date and check time with between clause.

What database are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Marc B that was really help full

Comment: Well, it seems like you sorted it out. Although it would be much more efficient if you do these validations at front end with coding. Try to put as less strain as possible on the database server.